# Call a virtual function inside the constructor using an object-expression

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }

    A(){ }
};

struct B : A
{
    B();
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
};

B b;

B::B()
{
    b.foo();
    foo();
}  

struct C : B
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }

    C() : B(){ }      
};

C c;

int main(){ }
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/aV5y5s)

> When a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a
>   constructor or from a destructor, including during the construction or
>   destruction of the class’s non-static data members, and the **object
>   to which the call applies is the object (call it x)** under
>   construction or destruction, the function called is the final
>   overrider in the constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one
>   overriding it in a more-derived class. If the virtual function call
>   uses an explicit class member access (5.2.5) and the **object
>   expression refers to the complete object of x** or one of that
>   object’s base class subobjects but not x or one of its base class
>   subobjects, the behavior is undefined.

I've been trying to recieve UB for

> If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access
>   (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x
>   [...]

It is unclear what means **complete object of x**, where `x` is an object. Is it the same as complete object of type of `x`?

Comment: You want the B constructor to call the over written C foo function?

Comment: How do you expect to recognize UB? The result could be anything, including masquerading as non-UB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

§1.8 [intro.object]/p2-3:

> Objects can contain other objects, called *subobjects*. A subobject
>   can be a *member subobject* (9.2), a *base class subobject* (Clause
>   10), or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any
>   other object is called a *complete object*.
>
> For every object `x`, there is some object called the *complete object
>   of `x`*, determined as follows:
>
> - If `x` is a complete object, then `x` is the complete object of `x`.
> - Otherwise, the complete object of `x` is the complete object of the (unique) object that contains `x`.

In essence, the sentence you cited makes doing `static_cast<C*>(this)->foo();` in `B`'s constructor undefined behavior in your code, even if the complete object being constructed is a `C`. The standard actually provides a pretty good example here:

```
struct V {
    virtual void f();
    virtual void g();
};
struct A : virtual V {
    virtual void f();
};
struct B : virtual V {
    virtual void g();
    B(V*, A*);
};

struct D : A, B {
    virtual void f();
    virtual void g();
    D() : B((A*)this, this) { }
};

B::B(V* v, A* a) {
    f();    // calls V::f, not A::f
    g();    // calls B::g, not D::g
    v->g(); // v is base of B, the call is well-defined, calls B::g
    a->f(); // undefined behavior, a’s type not a base of B
}
```

In fact, you can already [see the undefined behavior show up in this example if you run it](http://ideone.com/Xw8hUb): Ideone's compiler (GCC) actually calls `V::f()` on the `a->f();` line, even though the pointer is referring to a fully constructed `A` subobject.

Comment: I don't understand the comment here : `f(); // calls V::f, not A::f`. Why would anyone think of `A::f` here? Where does it come from into the picture? `A` is not in the inheritance. Looks like some typo. Same is with `// calls B::g, not D::g`.

Comment: Alright. I got it. B constructor is called from `D` constructor. In this example, `B` is treated as subject. Hence the comments.

Comment: @Nawaz Those aren't my comments :) I think they are on the assumption that the complete object being constructed is a `D`.

Comment: Welcome for the daily Standard Q/A Dmitry Fucintv | T.C. ... +1

Comment: @quantdev standards need love too!

Comment: @quantdev :D It's actually a good learning opportunity for me too - I probably read a lot more of the standard trying to answer those questions than I would otherwise.

Comment: So there is no UB if we remove all virtual specifiers from my example, right?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv In your example as written, there is no UB with or without the `virtual`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of tricky and I had to edit the post several times (thanks to the guys who helped me out), I'll try to get it simple and referring to N3690:

§12.7.4 states

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called during construction or destruction (12.6.2).

and this is what you've been doing in B's constructor

```
B::B()
{
    b.foo(); // virtual
    foo(); // virtual
}
```

This is perfectly legit for now. The *this* pointer (implicitly used in the second function call) always points to the object being constructed.

Then the standard also says:

> When a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a constructor and the object to which the
>   call applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction the function called is the final overrider
>   in the constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class (thus ignore the more-derived versions of the function)

so the vtable is not completely walked as you might think but stops to the constructor's class' version of the virtual function (see http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html).

Still legit.

Finally to your point:

> If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access e.g. 
>   (object.vfunction() or object->vfunction()) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x or one of that object’s base class subobjects but not x or one of its base class subobjects, (i.e. not the object under construction or one of its base class subobjects), the behavior is undefined.

to understand this sentence we first need to understand what a *complete object of x* means:

§1.8.2

> Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject (9.2), a base
>   class subobject (Clause 10), or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object is
>   called a complete object.
>
> For every object x, there is some object called the complete object of x, determined as follows:
>
> — If x is a complete object, then x is the complete object of x.
>
> — Otherwise, the complete object of x is the complete object of the (unique) object that contains x

if you put together the passage above with the previous one you get that you can't call a virtual function referring to "the complete type" of a base class (i.e. the derived object not yet constructed) or an object which owns that member or array element.

If you were to explicitly refer to C in B's constructor:

```
B::B() {
    static_cast<C*>(this)->foo(); // Refers to the complete object of B, i.e. C
}

struct C : B
{
    C() : B(){ }
}
```

then you would have had undefined behavior.

The intuitive (more or less) reason is that

- Calling a virtual or member function in a constructor is allowed and in case of virtual functions it "stops the virtual hierarchy walk" to that object and calls its version of the function (see http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html)
- Anyway if you do that from a subobject referring to a complete object of that subobject (re-read the standard passage), then it's undefined behavior

Rule of thumb: [don't call virtual functions in your constructors/destructors if you're not really sure you can](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/using-this-in-ctors.html).

In case I got something wrong please let me know in the comments below and I'll fix the post. Thanks!

Comment: `this->foo();` is just fine in `B`'s constructor. The type of `this` is `B*` in `B`'s constructor, after all.

Comment: Sure, but it's not fine when called from C I believe, the type should be C in that case

Comment: No, it's still `B *`. The type of `this` inside a constructor doesn't magically change depending on how a constructor is invoked.

Comment: Surely [you can't call a derived class' virtual functions from the base constructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/using-this-in-ctors.html) no matter how you do it

Comment: @MarcoA.: That's correct, you cannot call the virtual function of the derived class before it is constructed. Consequently, "the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class." But it's not UB.

Comment: I think that makes sense, I'll fix it a bit

Comment: @T.C. You're right with the this pointer: http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html sorry for the firedrill :)

Comment: @MarcoA.: No, it's still wrong. You're allowed to call a virtual method from a constructor of `x` if the target of the method is x or one of it's base classes. In this case, the (implicit) target is `this`, which is of type `x`, so there is no problem. (`this` is of type `B` inside the constructor for `B`. When the constructor for `C` is being executed, `this` will be of type `C`, but it won't necessarily be the same `this`; it will be part of the same complete object, but it might have a different address within that object.)

Comment: @rici Thanks for helping me understanding it. I've been getting this wrong for the whole time. I'll fix the post