# Calling a virtual function through a member-access expression

Tags: c++, base-class

I came acros the following rule `N4296::12.7/4 [class.cdtor]`:

> If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access
>   (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x
>   or one of that object’s base class subobjects but not x or one of its
>   base class subobjects, the behavior is undefined.

What does that mean? Couldn't you give an explanation of it with an example? It's a little bit hard to imagine that for me.

Comment: Doesn't it have an example immediately after that sentence?

Comment: In fact, didn't you ask [pretty much the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562042/call-a-virtual-function-inside-the-constructor-using-an-object-expression) ten months ago?

Comment: @T.C. Actually forget about that. I was wondered how you remebered about it...

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to know, this refers to when you are in the destructor of a base class and you refer to things of the the whole object that have already been destroyed.  An example:

```
struct Derived;

struct Base {
    Derived &der;
    Base(Derived &d): der(d) {}
    ~Base();
};

struct Derived: Base {
    int value;
    Derived(): Base(*this) {}
};

#include <iostream>

Base::~Base() {
    std::cout <<
        der.value // this is the undefined behavior! der.value is *gone*
        << std::endl;
}
```

AFAIK, everything in that code is legal except accessing `der.value` in the destructor of `Base` because when you are destroying `Base` you've already destroyed the `Derived` you kept a reference of in `der`